# $_GET inside of case

Tags: php

so I would like to use something like /action=productSpec?product=1
And then echo the value "1".
I have this:

```
        case "productSpec":
            $show = $_GET['product']
            echo $show;
            break;
```

But it doesn't work.
Why? Thank you.

"Case is also GET";

Comment: what is your main file name and main parameter to use. it's not clear enough.

Comment: You appear to be missing a semi-colon at the end of the $_GET and echo is spelt incorrectly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change that part in the URL to ?action=productSpec&product=1

Comment: If someone gives me a downvote, can you also explain why? According to the given information, this is the solution...